# Dumping complete terminal output of 2 combined commands to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here's a simplified version of the command I'm trying to run:

```
xtrabackup --backup --stream=xbstream | xbcloud put --storage=s3
```

Essentially what this does is generate a binary stream of a database backup and pipe it to another command which uploads it to AWS S3.

However, while this command is running, both `xtrabackup` and `xbcloud` echo output to the terminal. I want all of this output to go into a file instead.

I've tried adding `> file.txt` to the end but that only captures the output of the `xbcloud` command and not the `xtrabackup` command. I've also done some searching on SO and found suggestions that I should put `| tee file.txt` at the end but that just seems to result in an empty file.

Comment: Use the `script` command to capture all your terminal output into a file.

Comment: Since the stdout of `xtrabackup` is being written to the pipe, any output you're seeing from it must be coming from stderr (or, less likely, it's writing directly to `/dev/tty`). So you need to redirect stderr to the file with `2>file.txt`

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately I'm running the command on a docker image which is based on Red Hat's ubi8-minimal distro and the `script` command doesn't seem to be available. I just tried `2>file.txt` as per your suggestion (and also `2>>file.txt` but that still results in just the output of `xbcloud` going into the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following syntax, to:

- Collect all errors from the first command `xtrabackup` into a file named `xtrabackup-stderr.log`
- Collect all standard and error outputs of the second command `xbcloud` to a file named `xbcloud-all-output.log`

`xtrabackup --backup --stream=xbstream 2> xtrabackup-stderr.log | xbcloud put --storage=s3 &> xbcloud-all-output.log`

Does this satisfy your requirements?

##### Some details

In `Bash`:

- `1>` or `>` (considered as the same `1>`) redirects the `stdout` Stream Channel (known as Standard Output) to the defined file path.
- `2>` redirects the `sterr` Stream Channel (known as Standard Error Output) to the defined file path.
- `&>` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to the defined file path.
- `|` Known as Pipeline, passes the previous command's `stdout` to the next command/process.

*Note: You won't like to redirect the first command's `stdout` to a file since you are already passing its `stdout` to the next command to be processed via `|` pipeline, otherwise the second command `xbcloud` won't get any data to process/upload.*

###### Update #1

You may also separate the second command `stdout` and `stderr` to different files by:

`xtrabackup --backup --stream=xbstream 2> xtrabackup-stderr.log | xbcloud put --storage=s3 > xbcloud-stdout.log 2> xbcloud-stderr.log`

Comment: Thank you @Vab this satisfies the requirements exactly. I also appreciate the detailed explanation of why it works too. Do you think it would be ok to use the `>>` instead of `>` annd the same logfile name to get a combined log of both of these commands, or is there a risk that some log data would be lost doing this?

Comment: Glad that helps you @Joseph, using `>>`  or `2>>`  or `&>>`  for each manner will only cause to append the new data (from every new run of the commands) to the mentioned **file** instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @Joseph It might not work well because stdout is buffered when writing to a file. So you'll get error messages in the middle of xbcloud output.